# Masonry not working with Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-masonry

The inspirations are loaded as a single column instead of horizontally across the screen. It works if I take it out of the modal, but why not inside?

### Inside Modal

[image]

### Outside Modal

[image]

### _form

```
<div id="inspirations-margin" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= inspiration.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

### modals.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  modal_holder_selector = '#modal-holder'
  modal_selector = '.modal'

  $(document).on 'click', 'a[data-modal]', ->
    location = $(this).attr('href')
    #Load modal dialog from server
    $.get location, (data)->
      $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).
      find(modal_selector).modal()
    false

  $(document).on 'ajax:success',
    'form[data-modal]', (event, data, status, xhr)->
      url = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location')
      if url
        # Redirect to url
        window.location = url
      else
        # Remove old modal backdrop
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove()

        # Replace old modal with new one
        $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).
        find(modal_selector).modal()

      false
```

### inspirations.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#inspirations-margin').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#inspirations-margin').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

I see this guy ran into a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168628/masonry-js-not-working-with-modal-partial), but never got help.

Comment: Where are you running the masonry init code?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. `modals.js.coffee` is under app/assets/javascripts @yts

Comment: When you use masonry, you have to tell it to initialize. See here http://masonry.desandro.com/#initialize-with-jquery. You have to do this after the elements are in the DOM

Comment: Oh I think I see. I updated the question :) @yts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing masonry before the modal is displayed. You have to call it after you show the modal.

```
$(modal_holder_selector).html(data).
find(modal_selector).modal()
$('#inspirations-margin').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#inspirations-margin').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

That code should go in your callbacks where you show the modal

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I'm just adding to your code. Where you have `.modal()`, you have to initialize masonry afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying kind sir :)

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap modals:

```
$('#exampleModal').on( 'shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    gutter: 20,
    horizontalOrder: true
  });
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yMgyzR)